# Inserting data in sqlite database android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am using a prebuilt database stored in sdcard.I wanted to insert some values in that. while running insert code 0 byte journal file is building in sdcard but data intended to insert is not visible when i am looking into the database,why??? plz help..there is no error or warning.
      public void saveRecords(String site_reading, String Demand,String remarks){

```
    SQLiteDatabase mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("site_reading", site_reading); // inserting a string
    values.put("demand", Demand); // inserting an int
    values.put("remark", remarks);
    Log.e("in save records", site_reading + remarks + Demand);

   mDb.beginTransaction();
    mDb.insert("mst_mrt_1", null, values);
    mDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
    mDb.endTransaction();


}
```

And I am calling above method in an another Class as

```
    public void add_data(View v){
     d_name = veri.dataname;
     TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this,d_name);  
     mDbHelper.createDatabase();       

        String reading1 = info_reading.getText().toString();
        String Demand1 = info_demand.getText().toString();
        String remark1 = list.getSelectedItem().toString();
     mDbHelper.saveRecords(reading1,Demand1, remark1);
     mDbHelper.close();
}
```

Comment: Will you please post "mst_mrt_1" table structure from SQLite database class ?

Comment: WHat is the return value of mDb.insert("mst_mrt_1", null, values);??

Comment: @ManishAndroid database is in the .sqlite form,how to post it here plz tell me

Comment: @Tarun return value???

Comment: Insert returns **the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred** `long return = insert (....) print the value of return`.

Comment: You can use SQLite Browser for exploring your .sqlite db file.

Comment: @Tarun return value of insert(...) is 9999940012

Comment: @ManishAndroid i know that,but I am not able to post table here on stackoverflow..if I am doing so its structure is getting disturb,give me ur email Id.I'LL send it

Comment: 9999940012  doesnt look to be valid. 9999940012  is the row id in the database..

Comment: @SangeetaRawat I can't share my e-mail ID here, it is also against Privacy Policy and TOS of Stack Overflow. You can use pastie.org for sharing code. Just paste your code on pastie.org and send URL here.

Comment: @tarun I have got success in updating values in my database,but a new problem have arised.when I am accessing that updated data through my application,it is visible but when I am using sqlite manager to see my database updates are not visible..why?? plz help.also a sqlite-journal file is created in sdcard location.